# Navigating back to page from FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter, future

I have a submission form for my app where I have some data the user fills out in a form. I need to GET from an external API in the process, and use that data to create an entry in the database. All this happens once a Submit button is pressed, then after that I want to be able to go back to my homepage route.

I'm not sure how to get data from a Future function without using FutureBuilder, even though I don't need to build a widget, I just need the data.

This is what I have currently:

```
_populateDB() {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchPost(latitude, longitude),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _createJson(snapshot.data);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen()
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
}
```

The _populateDB() function is being called when a button is pressed on the screen. What I would like to do is get data from fetchPost(latitude, longitude), use that data in the function _createJson(snapshot.data), and finally go back to the HomeScreen().

I haven't implemented _createJson(snapshot.data) yet, but currently when I call this method with onPressed, it does not go back to the HomeScreen(), and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from a `Future function` in asynchronous way or in synchronous way.

## 1 Asynchronous way

It's simple, you can use Native Future API from dart. The method `then` is a callback method that is called when your Future is completed. You can also use `catchError` method if your future was completed with some error.

```
fetchPost(latitude, longitude).then(  
      (fetchPostResultsData) {
           if (fetchPostResultsData != null)
               print (fetchPostResultsData);
      }  ).catchError(  
               (errorFromFetchPostResults){
                   print(errorFromFetchPostResults);
               } 
       );
```

With this Approach your UI isn't blocked waiting results from network.

## 2 Synchronous way

You can use Dart key words `async` and `await` to keep your calls synchronized. In your case you have to transform your `_populateDB` method in an `async` method and `await` from `fetchPost` results.

```
_populateDB() async {
    var data = await fetchPost(latitude, longitude);
    // just execute next lines after fetchPost returns something.
    if (data !=null ){
        _createJson(snapshot.data);
        //... do your things
    } 
     else {
         //... your handle way
      }
 }
```

With this approach your `_populateDB` function will wait the results from `fetchPost` blocking the UI Isolete and just after getting the results will execute the next instructions.

About Navigation if your HomeScreen is the previous the previous widget on stack you just need `Navigator.pop(context)` call but if there are others widgets in the Stack above of your HomeScreen is a better choice use `Navigator.pushReplacement` call.

[This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) article shows in details with illustrations how the effects of `Navigator` methods. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet to solve it.

Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0))
.then((value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/routeName'));